# how to set a bridging header to libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to use libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumber in a swift project and I'm getting a file not found error in the bridging header

`#import <libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h>`

Pod file

`pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.7'`

https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

What should I be referencing to get it to find the pod?  libPhoneNumber-iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem: the "-" in the path gets replaced with an underscore automatically by cocoapods. Thus it should be

`#import <libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have bridging file then create at below

go file -> new -> iOS-> Source -> objective - C file and given name as project name

then after create 2 file one .m file and second .h file delete .m file

open yourprojname-bridging-header.h in write #import

more reference use this link [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: already have the bridging file and did as the instructions say - but the line `#import <libPhoneNumber-iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h>` in the bridging file shows the error

Comment: can you set path of bridging header file in bulid settings

Comment: the bridgin header file is already set up - no problem with the bridging file itself.  there is a problem with the import statement.  the error is noted in the question above -  file not found error